How is it possible for a file to be downloaded if the URL is incomplete?
I downloaded a video using a leeching site in Google Chrome. However, it won't
work in IDM (Internet Download Manager). When I click "Copy Address" from the
download link, I only get leechall.com instead of the full URL, which should
look something like leechall.com/sd56f5d4:

How is it possible for a file to be downloaded if the URL is incomplete?

This is usually dependent per server, because URIs don't have to be a 1:1 representation of a real path. However, I too can't envisage the server being quite as clever as your example. I'd re-evaluate that that video is entirely devoid of malware, considering it seems so happy to serve it.

@RokeJulianLockhart Video works fine, no playback issues. Just that URI looks spooky, how is that possible ?

I know spooky is not the word to fit here. Just weird by noticing download link is not exposing files path.

No such thing as "files path". URLs are just endpoints that connect the outside world with the executed code. Paths and parameters are completely optional. Is the copied link from the anchor exactly https://leechall.com? What's the HTML for the anchor? I'd check myself but this site is clearly half-malicious with some ad redirection loop on non-premium accounts.

@Destroy666 What's the HTML for the anchor? How to check it ?

Inspect the anchor element, from which you'll copying the URL, with right click -> inspect element or any similar menu entry. Then copy HTML and edit the question.

It's likely that the original video site doesn't provide a single video file that could be downloaded – e.g. YouTube no longer does; all you get is DASH or HLS segmented chunks (of audio and video separately!) – so the "downloader" website first needs to download all those chunks, which it likely does in-browser using JavaScript, then assembles them back into a continuous file and provides it for local "download" using JavaScript's Blob API.
So your browser isn't downloading anything from the downloader website's server; it is "downloading" from the webpage running on your computer.
(Other such websites might download and reassemble everything on their server, then host a regular file for you to download, but that has significant bandwidth costs – at least 2x the size of the video – and they're likely to get their IP address quickly blocked by the original video site.)
This isn't very unusual; in fact in many cases this is actually more-or-less the same as what the original video site itself does to play the video (e.g. when you click "Copy video link" and only get a blob:https:// URL, which is probably why you had to use a 'downloader' website in the first place).
